# Why does clicking @Url.Action throws an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I click a button input which triggers an action `ImagePopup` inside a controller `Stories` but it throws an error.

Code:

```
@{
    var listData = (List<HimHer.Models.Stories>)ViewBag.Grid;

    foreach (var imageName in listData)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Story)          
            <input
                class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"
                type="image"
                onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ImagePopup", "Stories", new {story= imageName.Story})'"
                src="@("/UploadedFiles/"+ imageName.Image)"
                alt="Submit"
                width="100%"
                height="100%"/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Upon clicking an input it throws an error:

> The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /Stories/ImagePopup

Even though it exists. It is right inside the Stories folder. It's a partial view without a model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImagePopup(string story)
{            
    ViewBag.PopupStyle = "";
    ViewBag.PopupStory = story;
    return View("GetImagesStories");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[HttpPost]` is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the href location of the current page:

```
location.href=
```

Causes the browser to do a Get Request type and does not post any form data back to your controller.  Because the method on your controller specifically only works for post requests (because of the `[HttpPost]` attribute) there is no other matching methods that could work, thus you get an Exception.

Solutions:

You can continue using the Get method.  Replace `[HttpPost]` with `[HttpGet]` will get you half way there.  The other requirement will be for you to make sure the `Url.Action` code contains all the necessary information to be posted back (for example all the data in `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Story)` is not included, I don't know if you need it or not).

Or

You can modify your code to use the Post method.  Change your `<input type="image"` to a `<button type="submit">` and add a form around each button and hidden input element.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for an HTTPGet Action I believe.
If you want to call your post, you'll need to use HTML.BeginForm but it can get hairy if there are too many on a page.

Answer (score 0):

try using `[HttpGet]` attribute for your `ImagePopup` action method